# Browser + Referrer not blocked by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, browser, blocking

I am trying to block some visitors from Russia.  The browser is like this:-
Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/)

The referrer is like this:_
http://mini-modus.ru/.......

I have this at the top of HTACCESS:-

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}mini-modus\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Re-re Studio (\+http://vip0\.ru/)" [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Followed by 2 newlines then:

```
order allow,deny
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

What is wrong with the code, please?

Comment: The line: deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is just to illustrate the rest of the htaccess file.

Comment: First of all, there appears to be a space missing between the arguments of your first RewriteCond.

Comment: If you don’t know the syntax, you can go read up on it. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: deleted the first rule.  The second rule :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Re-re Studio (\+http://vip0\.ru/)" [NC]
 if I use [NC,OR] instead if [NC], I get an error page Testing  123.  Any advice?

Comment: With just one condition, the OR flag makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you, but without the OR flag, am still getting numerius visitors with USER_AGENT Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/). Nerve racking :(